# Help with proof involving the Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory

Given the theorem:

A finite abelian group is isomorphic to a direct product of cyclic groups $\mathbb{Z}_{m_1} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{m_t}$ where each $m_i > 1$ and $m_i | m_{i+1}$.

Prove the following:

Let G be a non-trivial, finite abelian group. Let s be the smallest positive integer such that $G = <a_1,...,a_s>$ for some $a_1,...a_s \epsilon G$. Show that s is equal to the value of t above.

I need help starting this proof. Since $G = <a_1,...,a_s>$ what, if anything, can I state about G in relation to s? Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Comment: Also you can start by thinking about this: You know that $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{m_1}\times \dots \mathbb{Z}_{m_t}$ for some $t$. Since $a_1,\dots , a_s$ generate $G$, they also generate $\mathbb{Z}_{m_1}\times \dots \mathbb{Z}_{m_t}$. What is the minimal number of generators for the latter?

Comment: @Mathematician42 $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3=\mathbb{Z}_6$, so it can be put in the form he gives.

Comment: @Mathematician42 The theorem is correct, it's just formatted a little differently than the usual Fundamental Thm for Finite Abelian Groups. In the example you gave $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ would have to be written as $\mathbb{Z}_6$ since 2,3 are primes, but for example the thm says $\mathbb{Z}_{180} \simeq \mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{30}$

Comment: My mistake I'm so used to them being primes I imagined it was written down as well. My apolegies!

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thank you for your response. I'm assuming the minimum number of generators for the direct product group is t, but I'm not sure why. I understand it has to be more than one element to generate it since gcd($m_1,...,m_t$) $\neq$ 1, but it's not coming to me why it would have to be t. Any help, or even an example to help me understand would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Write $a_i=(a_{i1}, \dots , a_{it})$. Since the $a_i$'s generate $\mathbb{Z}_{m_1}\times \dots \mathbb{Z}_{m_t}$, there is an $i$ such that $a_{it}$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_{m_t}$. Now write the $a_i$'s in an $s\times t$ matrix. You can use the Gauss algorithm to eliminate the $a_{jt}$'s for all $j\neq i$. Proceed this idea. You should somewhere use that $m_i\mid m_{i+1}$ or equivalently that $\mathbb{Z}_{m_k}\times \mathbb{Z}_{m_{l}}$ is not cyclic and hence cannot be generated by one element. It's not the most streamlined argument, but it seems to work. You should conclude that $s\geq t$.